# Integration of the sequence problem

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I got a sequence $f_n$ given as following:

> $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0,  & \text{ $x \lt -\frac{1}{n}$} \\
>  cn^{\alpha}, & \text{ $-\frac{1}{n} \le x \lt 0$ } \\
>  -cn^{\alpha}, & \text{ $0 \le x \lt \frac{1}{n}$ } \\ 0, & \text{$x \ge \frac{1}{n}$ } \\ \end{cases}$

And I needed to integrate it, so to find $F_n$, which is given through the integral:

$F_n=\int _{\eta =-\infty}^{x}f_n(\eta)d \eta$

But I don't understand, what to do with the lower boundary. $f_n$ is outside the interval $(-1/n,1/n)$ zero everywhere. So I tried to integrate from $-1/n$ to $x$, but for the $-cn^{\alpha}$  it is wrong. I don't see it.

The textbook gives me the solution as:

> $F_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0,  & \text{ $x \lt -\frac{1}{n}$} \\
>  (x+\frac{1}{n})cn^{\alpha}, & \text{ $-\frac{1}{n} \le x \lt 0$ } \\
>  (-x+\frac{1}{n})cn^{\alpha}, & \text{ $0 \le x \lt \frac{1}{n}$ } \\
>  0, & \text{$x \ge \frac{1}{n}$ } \\ \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_n(\eta) \, \mathrm{d}\eta = \int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{0}f_n(\eta) \, \mathrm{d}\eta + \int_0^{x}f_n(\eta) \, \mathrm{d}\eta = \int_{-\frac{1}{n}}^{0}cn^{\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}\eta + \int_0^{x}(-cn^{\alpha})  \, \mathrm{d}\eta.$$

Comment: Interesting, I am going to try it. Thanks.